# Apache Camel Aggregator InOut Reply

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I'm trying to get a reply once the aggregator completes, but I'm getting an exception that I haven't specified any aggregator children, but when I specify a .to() endpoint I don't receive the aggregated result...is this even posisble?

Controller:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class App {
@Produce(uri = "direct:intake")
private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

public static void main(final String...args) {
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
}

@RequestMapping("/test/{message}")
public String test(@PathVariable String message) {
    return this.producerTemplate.requestBodyAndHeader("direct:intake", message, "id", "abc123").toString();
}
}
```

Aggregator:

```
@Component
public class Aggregator extends RouteBuilder {

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("direct:intake")
            .aggregate(header("id"))
            .aggregationStrategy(new AggregationStrategy() {
                @Override
                public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
                    if (oldExchange == null)
                        return newExchange;
                    oldExchange.getIn().setBody(oldExchange.getIn().getBody() + "::" + newExchange.getIn().getBody());
                    return oldExchange;
                }
            })
            .completionTimeout(5000)
            .to("stream:out");

}
}
```

Comment: If all of that stack trace is relevant, I would reformat it.

Comment: You're right it's messy...I cleaned it up.  Thanks!

Comment: Why are you aggregating like that? What does the reply needs to look like?

Comment: This is just test code to play with.  What I want is to be able to do is invoke a rest call, do some validation via multiple camel routes, and the results of those validations will be aggregated and returned to the caller (ProducerTemplate) to analyze the validation results.

Comment: what kind of endpoint did you add after the aggregator? I think a .to("mock:response") will work.

Comment: @PanayiotisPoularakis Yes, if I specify a .to() I receive an immediate result of the original request body.  The aggregated result will pass through the .to(), but not come back as a reply

Answer (score 0):

Someone on Twitter was kind enough to let me know that an aggregator's completed exchange is not returned in a reply.